# undefined reference to `...`, подключение SFML и hpp-файла

Tags: c++, g++

При попытке скомпилировать проект с использованием библиотеки `SFML` и собственных `hpp-файлов`, следующими командами:

```
g++ -c main.cpp list.cpp -I src/include
g++ -o main main.o list.o -L src/lib -l sfml-graphics-d -l sfml-window-d -l sfml-system-d -l winmm -l gdi32
```

Вылезает ошибка:

```
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x360): undefined reference to `list<float*>::list(float**, int)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

В `main.cpp` есть единственна строчка использования `list.hpp`

```cpp
list<float*> polygon(points, 4);
```

`points` - 2-ух мерный массив `float**`

list.hpp:

```cpp
#include <string>

template<class TypeClass>
class list{
    public:

        int size=1;
        TypeClass *arr = new TypeClass[1]{0};
        char status='s';

        list(){}
        list(TypeClass *arr_, int size_);

        void add(TypeClass var);

        void clean();

        void del(int index);

        void del_el(TypeClass elem);

        bool in(TypeClass elem);
};
```